# Application to monitor traffic spikes on cloud server?

Tags: cloud, traffic, rackspace-cloud

I was wondering if anybody knew of any software (preferably free if possible) that monitors server traffic for spikes?  Something that, say, might send out notifications via email or anything for that matter to let you know there's an unusually high volume of traffic at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Nagios or write your own script that monitors the current speed on the wire (vnstat or ntop output).

Comment: Nagios doesn't do this out of the box - I've got a simple awk script mashing my logs which Nagios reads from - but it's easy to set up Nagios and implement this.

Comment: It doesn't do it out of the box, but there are plenty of scripts on their website that do this

Comment: what do you mean by "on the wire?"

Comment: the speed at which you are sending/receiving packets